# Launching a .pl file using Process.Start

Tags: c#, perl

I have been using Process.Start to launch executables (.exe) files. Now I need to execute a .pl file with some arguments. can I still use Process.Start or I need a different approach?

**EDIT :- I am having to mark this question unanswered as I am getting the following error when I try to call the perl file from the CSharp code:-** (When I call the same from the commandline with the same path and parameters, It works fine)

**System.ApplicationException: StartProcess Failed
 System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform)**

Please note that when I try to call an .exe file from my C# code, I dont see the above error.

**EDIT:-
Checking the following link now:- [How do I call Perl script in C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649993/how-do-i-call-perl-script-in-c-application)
It seems that the ProcessStartInfo constructor has two parameters - fileName and the arguments. You should set Perl.exe as the fileName and the "argument" would be your perl file (.pl) with other arguments It accepts. Checking now....**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can :) you can also pass it arguments by adding them after the file name in

```
Process.Start(file.pl args1 args 2);
```

It will load the file with your default application for .pl files, the other option is to specify the software then pass your file as a parameter providing you have the right software to handle the file it should be fine

**Process.Start() can be pointed at any file and it will be opened using the default software or that which you specify, it need not be an executable.**

Comment: That is a great news for me at least. :-) Will give this a try. have you already tried this ever?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, Process.Start() takes a string parameter, what you pass for this parameter does exactly the same thing it would do if you entered the same string in the windows start -> run dialog.