# Call a perl script from vb.net with parameters

Tags: vb.net, perl, call

I'm using Visual Studio 08 and Vb.Net (3.5).

I want to call a perl script.
This perl script should get two values (that the user wrote into input-elements in the vb.net application).

Then the perl script should return one or more strings (maybe a list or an array?).

How can I do this?

Comment: solution but in c# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649993/how-do-i-call-perl-script-in-c-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `System.Diagnostics.Process` class to invoke an external executable or use `System.net.WebClient` class to request a url.